# Redirect www to non-www but don't touch subdomains

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect the main website URL using .htaccess from www to non-www but using the below snippet also affects my subdomain blog.mydomain.com. If I go into subdomain.mydomain.com I'm redirected straight to mydomain.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How can I except subdomains from the rule ?

Litespeed web server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(mydomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks @hjpotter92: Yes it should have been `%1` (fixed)